# What's the commands to run the apache beam mobile gaming tutorials?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am new to Apache Beam. I am reading the Word Count and Mobile Gaming tutorials. For Word Count, the commands to run the pipelines are given. However, there is no commands given in the tutorial to run Mobile Gaming.

https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/

https://beam.apache.org/get-started/mobile-gaming-example/

There are comments in the code, which help me figure out how to run the first two batch pipelines. However, I am not sure the commands about the last two streaming pipelines.

The comments also mentioned to use Injector to generate Pub/Sub data. I suppose it may have several steps to successfully run these streaming pipelines. Such as, create BigQuery table, generate pubsub data, run commands in terminal, ...

Would someone please help show me how to do this? Thanks!

I have tried the first two batch pipelines using the following command on Google Cloud Shell.

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.UserScore 
-Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner 
--project=MY_PROJECT_NAME 
--tempLocation=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/tmp 
--output=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/userScore" -Pdataflow-runner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I outlined all the steps below even though you are further then the beginning. This will help other users who may be stuck at a different step.

You first need to create a Maven project from the Apache Beam examples archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.12.0 \
      -DgroupId=org.example \
      -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
cd word-count-beam
```

---

**(one time setup)**

[Enable APIs](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=dataflow,compute_component,logging,storage_component,storage_api,bigquery,pubsub,datastore.googleapis.com,cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com&_ga=2.54492648.-1766341710.1555541401) within your GCP project.

Setup your default application credentials with `gcloud` so you can create Dataflow pipelines.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Create a GCS bucket that is writable to be used by the commands below.

---

To run the UserScore example:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Pdataflow-runner -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.UserScore -Dexec.args="--project=MY_PROJECT --tempLocation=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/tmp --runner=DataflowRunner --output=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/userscore"
```

---

To run the HourlyTeamScore example:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Pdataflow-runner -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.HourlyTeamScore -Dexec.args="--project=MY_PROJECT --tempLocation=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/tmp --runner=DataflowRunner --output=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/hourlyteamscore"
```

---

The LeaderBoard and GameStats examples rely on dynamic data being sent to Pubsub and processed in the pipeline. There is an Injector application that is responsible for publishing this data to Pubsub.

**(one time setup)** Before we run the injector. We need to create a set of credentials locally that will allow us to run the Injector without running into Pubsub quota issues. To do this you should:

1. [Create a service account within your GCP project. The service account should have access to Dataflow, GCS, Pubsub & BigQuery. Remember the service account e-mail address associated with it.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)
2. Fetch the service account credentials and save them to `CREDENTIALS_FILE`

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create CREDENTIALS_FILE --iam-account MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
```

---

To run the LeaderBoard example pipeline:

1. We first need to launch the injector (`MY_TOPIC_NAME` will be created if it doesn't exist):

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=CREDENTIALS_FILE mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.injector.Injector -Dexec.args="MY_PROJECT MY_TOPIC_NAME none"
```

2. We then create the output dataset in BigQuery:

```
bq mk MY_DATASET
```

3. Finally we run the LeaderBoard pipeline:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Pdataflow-runner -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.LeaderBoard -Dexec.args="--project=MY_PROJECT --tempLocation=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/tmp --runner=DataflowRunner --dataset=MY_DATASET --topic=projects/MY_PROJECT/topics/MY_TOPIC_NAME"
```

4. Go look at the table that was created within `MY_DATASET` to see the output as the pipeline is running.
5. Cancel the pipeline by pressing Ctrl+C.
6. Stop the Injector by pressing Ctrl+C.

---

To run the GameStats example pipeline:

1. We first need to launch the injector (`MY_TOPIC_NAME` will be created if it doesn't exist):

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=CREDENTIALS_FILE mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.injector.Injector -Dexec.args="MY_PROJECT MY_TOPIC_NAME none"
```

2. We then create the output dataset in BigQuery:

```
bq mk MY_DATASET
```

3. Finally we run the LeaderBoard pipeline:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Pdataflow-runner -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.GameStats -Dexec.args="--project=MY_PROJECT --tempLocation=gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/tmp --runner=DataflowRunner --dataset=MY_DATASET --topic=projects/MY_PROJECT/topics/MY_TOPIC_NAME"
```

4. Go look at the table that was created within `MY_DATASET` to see the output as the pipeline is running.
5. Cancel the pipeline by pressing Ctrl+C.
6. Stop the Injector by pressing Ctrl+C.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for your reply! I will try it out today!

Comment: A few comments on the above steps to avoid errors: 

1. The created Service Account must be with proper access. I chose Project Owner.

2. Make sure that PubSub, Dataflow, etc. APIs are enabled.

3. Make sure the Bucket is writable. Otherwise, create a new bucket which is writable.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer above with your additional details. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the *word-count* maven project setup, the java code for *mobile-gaming* examples are in the same project. You can run let say the first example called *UserScore* by executing this command.

```
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.complete.game.UserScore \
-Dexec.args="--output=user-scores"
```

The input GCS bucket for this public, but still you'll need to authenticate once using

```
 gcloud auth login
```

The output will be written into files prefixed with *user-scores*